# How to copy part of a string in rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling to copy part of a cell value(text) which is separated by - into the row down

[image]

Comment: Do you have any code to present?

Comment: Use `Split()` in VBA. Assuming your first `Desc.` value is in `B2` you can do: `Split(Range("B2"), "-")(0)` and it will spit out `12`. If you want to do it with cell formulas, then just `=Left(B2, Find("-", B2)-1)` to output `12`.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using a UDF here. I have the following loaded in as an "Add-in" so it's always available in Excel for me.

```
Function strtok(inString As String, delimiter As String, position As Integer) As String
    strtok = Split(inString, delimiter)(position - 1)
End Function
```

That's very lightweight, but now in an excel formula you can do something like:

[image]

Of course you can also use it in VBA. It's really the same functionality I mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: Dates get a bit wonky with Excel.  I am curious how this works, or if this works, when date formats are changed.  Guess I have to test it and find out!

Comment: Oh. Yeah. Won't work with dates. In that case just use a formula to get the month.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2010 or later, you can do this easily with Power Query.

In 2016, you would:

- Select a cell in your table
- `Data ==> Get&Transform ==> from table/range`
- And then just select to split the Desc column by Delimiter into Rows:

[image]

Voilá:

[image]